# Can there be a pressure gradient in a large enough closed container?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, atmospheric-science

If we had an airtight container that was large enough, say extended out to the Karman line, would there still be a pressure gradient? If we assume that the pressure at the bottom was $1\ \mathrm{atm}$, would it have the same exact pressure gradient at 6 miles up on the outside? This is assuming that the gravity is still $9.8\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$.

Answer (score 7):

The pressure gradient would be in any container that is in a gravitational field.  It's just that in most situations, the gradient in air is too small to worry about and it is ignored.

You can determine the gradient the same way you do pressure underwater.  You just multiply the depth of the fluid by the density.  For very large columns, the density of air would vary.  But for a small container, we can assume it's nearly constant, around $\rho = 1.225\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$

That means near sea level, if the pressure at the bottom of a container is $1\ \mathrm{atm}$ or about $1013\ \mathrm{mbar}$, the pressure $1\ \mathrm m$ higher would be less by the weight of that amount of air.

$$\Delta p = \rho gh$$ 
$$\Delta p = (1.225\ \mathrm{kg/m^3})(9.81\ \mathrm{m/s^2})(1\ \mathrm m)$$
$$\Delta p = 0.12\ \mathrm{mbar}$$

$1\ \mathrm m$ up in your container, the pressure is less by about $0.01\ \%$.